# Can I use @ComponentScan and @Autowired with BasicDataSource without declare bean for BasicDataSource class in XML?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, autowired, component-scan

I'm trying to integrate hibernate with spring, and I asked-just to know if that possible or not-, can I use @Autowired and @Componentscan to do inject the BasicDataSource class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `@ComponentScan` you can avoid declaring beans by loading them from Java-based configurations. This way, you still need a `@Configuration` to provide a `BasicDataSource` dependency.

After the `BasicDataSource` dependency is scanned, it can be injected in other Spring components using `@Autowired` or `@Inject`.